# Where is the line drawn between mathematics and mathematical software used by mathematicians?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I saw a [similar question on the Statistical Analysis meta](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252/should-we-allow-more-computing-questions), but I didn't see any discussion here, so I figured I'd kick this off to the "power users" of Mathematics. Where are the boundaries when it comes to tools like computer algebra systems, numerical analysis software, geometry software, and theorem provers?

Should questions about choosing and using these tool be allowed or should they be off-topic?

Comment: To get some data on how we would deal with it you could check out:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153/what-should-i-learn-first-mathematica-or-matlab, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29/can-you-recommend-a-decent-online-or-software-calculator, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985/software-for-drawing-geometry-diagrams, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6/what-is-your-favorite-online-graphing-tool .

Comment: Or more generally, search for tag [`math-software`](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math-software). To my knowledge, the only software question closed was about TeX, for which there exists an excellent SE2.0 site already.

Comment: I saw a few of those questions, but they don't address use yet. No one has asked a question about how they do X or Y in MATLAB yet...at least, not that I could find (but I was really lazy in searching).

Comment: Never mind...that tag has questions like what I'm thinking. This question can be closed.

Answer (score 5):

IMO your question has a very clear answer, to me, and I suspect to most professional mathematicians.  So I'd say it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

I think a good test is first whether the topic is suited for StackExchange (ie not overly subjective) and then whether this is the most appropriate site. Based on this, I say this is on topic.